# Dictionary comprehension with list comprehension as values

Tags: python

I'm fairly certain the solution to this wouldn't be pythonic at all, but I'm curious to see how one would actually go about doing it. Assuming I have data that looks like:

```
data = {"things": 
           {"hello": [{"fruit": "orange"}, {"fruit": "apple"}], 
            "world": [{"fruit": "banana"}, {"fruit": "cherry"}]
           }
        }
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
[{"hello": ["orange", "apple"]}, {"world": ["banana", "cherry"]}]
```

I've tried a few things but can't quite seem to figure out the best combo. I've tried using `groupby` and `sorted` per some related examples found

```
d = dict([(word, list(fruits)) for word, fruits in groupby(sorted(data['things'], key=lambda x: data['things'][x]['fruit']), key=lambda x: data['things'][x])])
```

Like I said this is just for fun and to figure out how to combine things. I realize that it is not efficient or the most pythonic way to go about this.

Comment: You can more cleanly make a dict comprehension like `{k:v for k, v in iter}` .. however, it's often cleanest to simply start with an empty dict and add to it with a `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, just a straight comprehension.

```py
>>> [{k: [d["fruit"] for d in v]} for k, v in data["things"].items()]
[{'hello': ['orange', 'apple']}, {'world': ['banana', 'cherry']}]
```